# Shortening Python Code

Tags: python

I have code that looks like this:

```
image = np.ones(content_image.shape, dtype=np.float32)
     for i, curr_point in enumerate(curr_good_points):
           a, b = curr_point.ravel()
           for row in range(int(a - BLOCK_LENGTH/2), int(a + (BLOCK_LENGTH+1)/2)):
              if row < 0 or row >= image.shape[1]:
                 continue
              for col in range(int(b - BLOCK_LENGTH/2), int(b + (BLOCK_LENGTH+1)/2)):
                 if col < 0 or col >= image.shape[2]:
                       continue
                 for color_channel in range(image.shape[3]):
                       image[0][row][col][color_channel] = 0
```

Basically, for every a,b pair in curr_good_points, I'd like to mark a box around each point in each color channel, basically blocking it out.

If you could help me shorten this code I'd be really grateful! Thanks.

Comment: Your question would probably work better over at our sister site [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). You'd need to make a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show them though.

Comment: Does it work?  Why do you need it shortened?